# Why is the whole ArrayList list removed when calling the remove method?

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist, persistence

To start I have two entities.

User.java

```java
@Entity
public class User { 
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "to", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval=true)
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;
}

public void deleteMessage(Message message){
        System.out.println(messages);
        messages.remove(message);
        System.out.println(messages);
}
```

Message.java

```java
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    @NoGson
    private User to;
}
```

The ArrayList messages contains messages for that user and every message in that list has as the "to" field that user. All this is persisted correctly. When I however run the deleteMessage method the first sysout gives the full list correctly and the seconds sysout just gives null instead of the list without the deleted message.

I don't know if it has something to do with jpa or if I'm just making a stupid mistake but I can't find the reason why the remove method just removes the entire ArrayList. When I call the deleteMessage function I also call the remove method of the entity manager to delete the message from the database.

### Update

After more testing I noticed that the second sysout does give the correct output. So the problem isn't the remove method from the ArrayList. But the arraylist becomes null after executing the following method.

```java
public void deleteMessage(Message message) {
    em.remove(message);
}
```

So now I know it is a JPA problem.

Comment: `remove` actually returns a boolean value. Is that value `true` or `false` ? Also, are you sure you're not adding a single `Message` and then removing it ? (leaving the `ArrayList` empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by resetting the *to* field of the message that has to be deleted to null. This way the bidirectional connection is broken. If I run the *deleteMessage* method from above again the ArrayList doesn't change to null and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be saying is that before `messages.remove()`, `messages` is a reference to a list, but afterward, the reference is null. If that's true, then the possibilities are fairly limited. There could be another thread modifying state, or there could be some aspect-oriented magic happening. You would probably benefit from attempting to [provide an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), as you'll either discover the problem yourself along the way.